# EF Core Repository items not tracked after insert with ExecuteSqlRaw(commandText)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern, aspnetboilerplate

Because of the performance benefits, I am inserting data by executing raw sql command.
All data are properly inserted into database, but the repository is not aware of them being inserted. Basically, **usersBeforeInsert** and **usersAfterInsert** contain the same 3 records.

Also, after application restart, repository is still not aware of users inserted with ExecuteSqlRaw(), retrieving only users that existed prior to ExecuteSqlRaw().

Does anybody knows how to make _userRepository retrieve all data from db? Btw, I am using asp.net boilerplate project.

Here is the code sample:

```
var usersBeforeInsert = await _userRepository.GetAllListAsync();      // 3
var commandText = GenerateInsertUsersSqlScript(users);
var context = _userRepository.GetDbContext();
var rowsAffected = context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(commandText);       // 85000
context.SaveChange()
var usersAfterInsert = await _userRepository.GetAllListAsync();      // 3
```

Comment: Could you expand a little bit on what you mean by "the repository is not aware of them being inserted" ? Do you mean the repository cannot retrieve them ? Also, what type of object if _userRepository ?

Comment: it works as it should ... if you wana get inserted items after raw insert you should call GetAllListAsync after insert ... edit: *Also, after application restart ... repository is still not aware* ...  maybe `context.SaveChange()` deletes users which are not in `usersBeforeInsert` (or `commandText`  is adding something to different table)

Comment: @MarleneHE By "not aware of" I meant that when you try to retrieve data after the ExecuteSqlRaw() command, it returns only the records that were in database prior to ExecuteSqlRaw() .
Basically, usersBeforeInsert  and usersAfterInsert  contain the same 3 records. 

The repository is of type IRepository<User, long>.

Comment: Are you trying to insert  `// 85000` rows? Check data is inserted successfully into the database. Check if EF Core in your project uses cache.

Comment: @Shone we can't guess what that "repository" does. What's certain is that it's not needed. A DbSet is already a repository, a DbContext is a Unit-of-Work. `SaveChanges` will store *all* changes since it was last called. The "generic repository" *anti*pattern makes using EF Core a lot harder. Your `Insert` may be performing 500 DELETEs on the side for example

Comment: As for inserting 85000 rows - that's not what ORMs are for. They are meant to Map Object entities to Relational constructs. Entities have behavior. You have no entities with 85K rows, you have just rows with data. It would be a *lot* better if you used ADO.NET for this, or better yet, SqlBulkCopy. Going through the ORM, double caching the data, checking for changes when you already know the data is all knew, is only causing delays

Comment: Or better yet, use your database's bulk import tools to import the data directly into a table, eg `bcp` or `SSIS`. SqlBulkCopy is essentially a BCP engine accessible from .NET

Comment: please show the codes of GetAllListAsync and GenerateInsertUsersSqlScript

Answer (score 0):

Your culprit is this line

```
var usersBeforeInsert = await _userRepository.GetAllListAsync();
```

Because the framework assume nothing has changed between this line and this line

```
var usersAfterInsert = await _userRepository.GetAllListAsync();
```

You fix this by not calling the list until after the raw insert, or you can clear the changeset.

the easiest way to clear the changeset is to new up a new _userRepository, but I guess it most likely is injected.